# Conversion of Unix timestamp in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date

I have a Web Api returning a datetime  feild as below
I know its unix stamp , And I can convert it if i consider the numeric part only

```
"InvoiceDate":"/Date(1590696000000)/"
```

Can anyone suggest me to directly convert the above to date variable in javascript

NB. I had already done enough search on stackoverflow. but cannot find a question close enough for the same format.so posted considering somebody with same query in future too

Comment: this should help https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_new_millisec

Comment: you can use the eval function, however the starting and ending `/` has to be removed

Comment: Looks like your web api is .net / c# - do you have an option to change the web api?  It's much cleaner/easier than hacking the json return.

Comment: `new Date(+(InvoiceDate.match(/\d+/) || [])[0])`